# Swift import mechanism

Tags: swift

I am using SnapKit.swift and other framework. I wonder why sometime I need to add `import SnapKit.swift` and why sometime I don't have to in file that use SnapKit.

Can anyone point me to some resource about how Swift import system works?

Edit: The below code works all fine without importing SnapKit

```
import UIKit

class ImageEditViewController: UIViewController {

    private var imageView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage.init(named: "img.jpg"))
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.center.equalTo(self.view)
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the fact, you have to `import SnapKit` whenever you use it directly in a Swift file. You can't use it unless you import it.

In another hand, if other framework already import `SnapKit`, you don't need to import it again.

i.e: In swift standard lib.

If you want to use Foundation, you should `import Foundation`.
If you `import UIKit`, you don't need to `import Foundation`, because UIKit already had `import Foundation`

Answer (score 0):

This i because that the `import` statement in Swift works very differently from other languages like Python and Java. And let me clarify some terminology here, what you `import` is called a "module", not a framework.

In Swift, some modules import other modules. e.g. The UIKit module imports Foundation. So when you import UIKit, you don't need to import Foundation anymore. Because UIKit already imports it.

So in your case, you always have to `import SnapKit` in your swift file in order to use the stuff in it, just like the Foundation example. However, if you import another module that imports SnapKit, (I don't know anything about this so) let's call it `MyKit`. You just need to write

```
import MyKit
```

to use all the stuff in SnapKit *and* MyKit!

**In short, some modules import other ones. This is why you sometimes can omit imports.**

Comment: I have added code snippet. I think UIKit in this case does not import SnapKit. And my code still works.

Comment: Why doesn't you think UIKit import SnapKit? @MortyChoi

Comment: As SnapKit is an open source lib in github and UIKit is apple official sdk. I dont think official module will import an open source module.